# Extract the lines using sed or awk and save them in file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Dear Stackoverflow Community,

I am trying to grab the value or the part of the string or lines.

The Kubernetes init gives 2 **kubeadm join** commands.

I want to extract the first one and save it in a file and similarly extract the 2nd one and save it in a file.

Below is the text that I am trying to extract from the file:

```
You can now join any number of the control-plane node running the following command on each as root:

  kubeadm join 10.0.0.0:6443 --token jh88qi.uch1l58ri160bve1 \
    --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:f9c9ab441d913fec7d157c20f1c5e93c496123456ac4ec14ca8e02ab7f916d7fb \
    --control-plane --certificate-key 179e288571e33d3d68f5691b6d8e7cefa4657550fc0886856a52e2431hjkl7155

Please note that the certificate-key gives access to cluster sensitive data, keep it secret!
As a safeguard, uploaded-certs will be deleted in two hours; If necessary, you can use
"kubeadm init phase upload-certs --upload-certs" to reload certs afterward.

Then you can join any number of worker nodes by running the following on each as root:

kubeadm join 10.0.0.0:6443 --token jh88qi.uch1l58ri160bve1 \
    --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:f9c9ab441d913fec7d157c20f1c5e93c496123456ac4ec14ca8e02ab7f916d7fb
```

**Goal -**

Extract both kubeadm join commands and save them in different files for automation.

**Commands Used till now -**

`sed -ne '/--control-plane --certificate-key/p' token`
With the above command, I want to extract value if I can and save it in a file.

The other command -

```
awk '/kubeadm join/{x=NR+2}(NR<=x){print}' token
```

**token** is the filename

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show the expected output so it's a bit of a guess but this:

```
awk -v RS= '/^ *kubeadm join/{print > ("out"NR); close("out"NR)}' file
```

should do what I think you want given the input you provided.

Comment: Thanks, ED for the reply, but the above solution didn't work. Got this error ```awk -v RS= '/^ *kubeadm join/{print > "out"NR; close("out"NR)}' token
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 /^ *kubeadm join/{print > >>>  "out"NR <<< ; close("out"NR)}
awk: illegal statement at source line 1```

Comment: i used these 2 commands to pull the lines that I want -                                             
   ```sed -n 73,75p ./token                                                                                                                        
        sed -n 83,84p ./token``` Only drawback is if the output stored in token file change then these 2 commands will fail. And I want to extract 3 lines of first kubeadm join and 2 lines of 2nd kubeadm join

Comment: Wow - rookie mistake on my part not putting parens around the concatenation that produces the file name to make it portable, fixed now, sorry about that.

Comment: Forget sed, just use the awk script. sed is great for doing s/old/new on simple strings, for anything else just use awk for some combination of simplicity, clarity, portability, robustness, efficiency, etc.